# Is this the correct implementation of an insertion sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, insertion-sort

Hello I have done an insertion sort in Java but I do not know whether I have implemented this correctly. Can anybody collaborate ?
I think insertion sort needs to include a while loop within a for loop
hence I implemented this but I do not know whether it is correct.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------

import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.Arrays;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class Insertionsort {
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // --------------------------------------------- insertion sort
        int mainInsersionSortArray[] = {64, 25, 12, 22, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3};
        int insertionSortTemporaryValue = 0;
        System.out.println("Array before insertion sort");
        for (int z = 0; z < mainInsersionSortArray.length; z++) {
            System.out.println(mainInsersionSortArray[z]);
        }

        int x1;
        for (int k0 = 1; k0 < mainInsersionSortArray.length; k0++) {
            x1 = k0;
            while (x1 != 0) {
                if (mainInsersionSortArray[x1] < mainInsersionSortArray[x1 - 1]) {
                    insertionSortTemporaryValue = mainInsersionSortArray[x1];
                    mainInsersionSortArray[x1] = mainInsersionSortArray[x1 - 1];
                    mainInsersionSortArray[x1 - 1] = insertionSortTemporaryValue;
                }
                x1 = x1 - 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "Array after insertion sort");
        for (int z1 = 0; z1 < mainInsersionSortArray.length; z1++) {  // integerArray.lenght - looping through the whole array starting from i[0]
            System.out.println(mainInsersionSortArray[z1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Insertion sort implemented in java.

Comment: first of all, please *format* your code, then why are you asking in the first place? Does it work or not? When it doesn't then please provide a sample input the expected output as well as the actual output

Comment: You'll need to test it yourself, I'm afraid. Stack Overflow works well for specific questions with enough detail to identify an answer. Debugging and testing are outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also it's more likely a `Bubblesort` than an `Insertionsort` algorithm

Comment: Hi, the code is working, and sorting the array, however I do not know whether I have done an insertion sort or somehow a different sort (e.g. bubble sort/selection sort). ?

Comment: @ekcs You should be able to compare your code against other insertion sort code or visualizations of insertion sort you can find online. If you understand, logically, what insertion sort is supposed to do, you should be able to tell whether this is what your code is doing (if you're writing code you don't understand, you have bigger problems).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that after a number of steps of the algorithm, the part `A[0:k[` (i.e. `k` excluded) of the array is sorted. In the next step, we consider the element `A[k]`, search its insertion place and shift all elements after this location. This is better done in a single pass by keeping a copy of `A[k]`, shifting the larger elements and putting the copied element at the right place. To avoid buffer overflow, the search should stop at index `0`.

The inner loop reads

```
int Save= A[k];
for ( ; k >= 0 && A[k-1] > Save; k--) // Loop until you can insert
{
    A[k]= A[k-1]; // Shift
}
A[k]= Save;
```

A slightly better variant avoids unnecessary copies if `A[k]` is already at the right place:

```
if (A[k] <= A[k-1])
{
    int Save= A[k];
    A[k]= A[k-1]; // Shift
    for (k--; k >= 0 && A[k-1] > Save; k--) // Loop until you can insert
    {
        A[k]= A[k-1]; // Shift
    }
    A[k]= Save;
}
```

Beware that it can only be used provided `k > 0`.

Now the outer loop just grows the sorted part `A[0..j[` with

```
for (j= 1; j < n; j++)
{
    k= j;
    "Inner loop"
}
```